# Suggest me plugin/widget (sidebar) for Sharing posts

Tags: plugins

Actually, i am an android programmer, but own a blog to post android tutorials, examples....etc. etc.

I have noticed below plugin/widget on the left-side of an article on many websites, so can you please suggest me whats that plugin actually?

Thanx,
Paresh

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**[Digg Digg](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/digg-digg/)** plugin allows you to display popular social sharing buttons with count, such as Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, Google +1, Reddit, StumbleUpon and Pinterest, among many others.

On the plus side, the plugin does lazy loading to increase website performance.

Comment: I have installed and activated digg digg plugin but getting error `Notice: Undefined property: DD_Buffer::$dd_twitter_ajax_left_float`, yes floating bar at left is visible but above error is being displayed.

Comment: @PareshMayani That issue has been fixed in the later versions of Digg Digg plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Add Twitter, Facebook Like, Google plus one Social share***
http://www.searchtechword.com/2011/06/wordpress-plugin-add-twitter-facebook-google-plus-one-share/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple share buttons , those js powered buttons will slow your site down dramatically. try this one :

[Simple Share Buttons Adder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/)